# Acumatica REST API GET is suddenly throwing a SqlClient syntax error

Tags: acumatica

A simple REST API GET command is suddenly throwing a SqlClient syntax error.  The GET looks like this:

http://localhost/acumaticaerp/entity/default/17.200.001/SalesOrder/SO/036307

The response is a 500 error and looks like this:

```
{
    "message": "An error has occurred.",
    "exceptionMessage": "Incorrect syntax near '='.",
    "exceptionType": "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException",
    "stackTrace": "   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)\r\n   at PX.Data.PXSqlDatabaseProvider.ExecuteReaderInternal(IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)\r\n   at PX.Data.PXSelectResult.PXSelectResultEnumerator.System.Collections.IEnumerator.MoveNext()\r\n   at PX.Data.PXView.GetResult(Object[] parameters, PXFilterRow[] filters, Boolean reverseOrder, Int32 topCount, PXSearchColumn[] sorts, Boolean& overrideSort, Boolean& extFilter)\r\n   at PX.Data.PXView.Select(Object[] currents, Object[] parameters, Object[] searches, String[] sortcolumns, Boolean[] descendings, PXFilterRow[] filters, Int32& startRow, Int32 maximumRows, Int32& totalRows)\r\n   at PX.Data.PXGraph.ExecuteSelect(String viewName, Object[] currents, Object[] parameters, Object[] searches, String[] sortcolumns, Boolean[] descendings, PXFilterRow[] filters, Int32& startRow, Int32 maximumRows, Int32& totalRows)\r\n   at PX.Data.PXGraph.ExecuteSelect(String viewName, Object[] parameters, Object[] searches, String[] sortcolumns, Boolean[] descendings, PXFilterRow[] filters, Int32& startRow, Int32 maximumRows, Int32& totalRows)\r\n   at PX.Api.SyImportProcessor.SyStep.SelectRows(String viewName, PXFilterRow[] filters, Int32 topCount, Boolean bypassInserted, Int32 startRow, SyExportContext exportContext)\r\n   at PX.Api.SyImportProcessor.ExportTableHelper.a(SyStep A_0, GrowingTable A_1, SyCommand A_2, PXFilterRow[] A_3, Int32 A_4)\r\n   at PX.Api.SyImportProcessor.ExportTableHelper.ExportTable()\r\n   at PX.Api.ContractBased.ExportTableHelperExtensions.RunExportAndAssertSuccess(SyExportContext exportContext) in F:\\Bld2\\AC-FULL2017R210-JOB1\\sources\\NetTools\\PX.Api.ContractBased\\EntityService.cs:line 814\r\n   at PX.Api.ContractBased.EntityService.GetList(ISystemContract systemContract, String version, String name, EntityImpl entity, Boolean returnFullEntities, CbOperationContext operationContext, Boolean ignoreValueFields, PXGraph graph) in F:\\Bld2\\AC-FULL2017R210-JOB1\\sources\\NetTools\\PX.Api.ContractBased\\EntityService.cs:line 75\r\n   at PX.Api.ContractBased.EntityService.GetImpl(ISystemContract systemContract, String version, String name, EntityImpl entity, Boolean returnFullEntity, EntityExportContextBuilder entityExportContextBuilder, EntityDescriptor entityDescriptor, CbOperationContext operationContext) in F:\\Bld2\\AC-FULL2017R210-JOB1\\sources\\NetTools\\PX.Api.ContractBased\\EntityService.cs:line 333\r\n   at PX.Api.ContractBased.EntityService.Get(ISystemContract systemContract, String version, String name, EntityImpl entity, CbOperationContext operationContext, Boolean returnFullEntity, PXGraph graph) in F:\\Bld2\\AC-FULL2017R210-JOB1\\sources\\NetTools\\PX.Api.ContractBased\\EntityService.cs:line 269\r\n   at PX.Api.ContractBased.Soap.SoapFacadeBase.GetImpl(EntityImpl entity) in F:\\Bld2\\AC-FULL2017R210-JOB1\\sources\\NetTools\\PX.Api.ContractBased\\Soap\\SoapFacadeBase.cs:line 98\r\n   at PX.Api.ContractBased.SystemContracts.V2.SoapFacade.PX.Api.ContractBased.IRestGate.Get(EntityImpl entity) in F:\\Bld2\\AC-FULL2017R210-JOB1\\sources\\NetTools\\PX.Api.ContractBased\\SystemContracts\\V2\\SoapFacade.cs:line 46\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()"
}
```

If I use a SO # that doesn't exist, it gives me the appropriate error that it doesn't exist, but when it does, I get an error.  Any ideas?

[Update 8/14/19] A SQL trace shows a broken JOIN statement on the ShipmentNbr segment:

```
<select>
FROM [SOOrderShipment] [SOOrderShipment]
LEFT JOIN [SOShipment] [SOShipment] ON [SOShipment].CompanyID = 2 AND = [SOOrderShipment].[ShipmentNbr] AND [SOShipment].[ShipmentType] = [SOOrderShipment].[ShipmentType]
```

Comment: It seems like Acumatica is building a SQL query incorrectly. This might occur by using unbound fields in a query where condition or join condition. And unbound field might be a field that uses PXString vs PXDBString or the other PX non db types. I also see this when using PXProjections and trying to use a CacheExtension. Try to do an Acumatica request profiler or SQL profiler to see which query is having issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my issue.  I had a PXSelector in my graph that shouldn’t have been there, and there was an issue with its join.  I removed it and now am ok.